# Is the rendering of a child component in react different from react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, rerender

First of all, I have a basic level in english. So I hope you understand.

Is the rerender of a child component in react native different in react?
Let me give you an example:

```
class App extends React.Component{

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

 render(){
    return(
        <ChildComponent />
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({test:'test'})
  }

}
```

this in react rerender ChildComponent once, but in React Native ChildComponent not rerender only have your initial render. Why?

ps: ChildComponent have just a div in React and Text in React Native.

Comment: You mean you can't see the text in ChildComponent on React-native?

Comment: I can. but if I put a console.log('test') in render method of ChildComponent, on react i see 'teste' twice and on react native once. The deubt is not the text shown, 
but the amount of times that method render of the ChildComponent is called.

Answer (score 0):

No in react and react native both rendering the child component is same. Let us take an example

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Child from './Child'

export default class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Hi I am a parent component </Text>
                <Child/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> This is child </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```